# Connection get/return listener?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc

Using Hibernate and Spring, my app needs to get the opportunity to manipulate the connection at the start and end of every database update.  Our first guess was to override the transaction manager, but that is seeming to have some side effects from an intermittent "Pre-bound JDBC Connection found!" error to a few other harder to describe symptoms.

What is the best/easiest way to get this oppostunity.  I saw someone suggest overriding the data source and then wrapping the connection, but is that really the best idea?  Wrapping the connection seems dangerous, espceially since Websphere has it's own version (WSconnection).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Manipulation of the connection is done the easiest when a `DataSource.getConnection` is done, that way you know for certain that something is going to happen. So you could simply create a DataSourceProxy/-Wrapper (give it a name) which does this. There is one thing you have to take care of and that is, probably on close of the connection, that you undo the manipulation (if that is needed that is).

Instead of creating a proxy you could use some AOP to execute the code (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782008/execute-database-session-initialization-sql-in-spring-jdbc).